# import column name and data with separate files in R

Tags: r, dataframe, r-colnames

I would like to import a txt file only contains one line as table column name and append with the other csv file with only data. The simplified files are as below:

txt file

```
Precentral Frontal_Sup Frontal_Sup_Orb
```

and the csv file

```
0.9938  0.96507 1.0043
```

And final outcome I want is

```
Precentral Frontal_Sup Frontal_Sup_Orb
0.9938       0.96507    1.0043
```

I've tried this but it does work

```
AAL <- rbind(read.table('raw data/header.txt', header = TRUE), read.csv('raw data/data.csv', header = FALSE))
```

And the outcome is

```
V1         V2       V3
0.9938   0.96507  1.0043
```

How to solve this? Thanks very much!

Comment: I think you need `nm1 <- scan('raw data/header.txt', what ="", sep = " ", quiet = TRUE)` and then you name the data read with `names(df1) <- nm1`

Comment: ....and combine that with `read.csv("file.csv", col.names=scan(...))`

Comment: Thanks very much! This works prefectly!!

Comment: You are rbinding two data frames with different headers. If you had used `bind_rows` from dplyr you would have noticed that you get 6 columns instead of 3.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to akrun and  thelatemail. It works by using

```
AAL <- read.csv("data.csv", col.names=scan('raw data/header.txt', what ="", sep = "\t", quiet = TRUE))
```